# NSMutableData datawithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: seems to make a copy of the buffer provided to it

Tags: cocoa, nsdata

According to Apple documentation, the class method

+datawithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:

inherited from NSData

> Creates and returns a data object that holds a given number of bytes from a given buffer.

But

```
NSUInteger len = 1024;
char *buffer = malloc(len);
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:len freeWhenDone:YES];
char *dataBytes = data.mutableBytes;
NSLog(@"%@", dataBytes == buffer ? @":D" : @":(");
```

prints

```
:(
```

The method seems to actually make a copy, where I expected it not to.
Am I using this the wrong way?
The equivalent NSData method works as expected.
How would I create an NSMutableData object pointing to an already existing buffer without taking any ownership?

Comment: I don't  get it either... I'd expect :D too -- smells like a bug maybe

Comment: I've reported this as a bug in the past, and Apple said it was intentionally that way. Highly annoying. According to them, "This behaves as expected—avoiding this copy would result in too many scenarios where something typed as an NSData is expected to have unchangeable contents from -bytes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that you just can't do what you want to do.  After all, if you have an `NSMutableData` and append some more data to it, then the buffer would need to be reallocated, and no longer use the pointer you supplied.

Apple's [Binary Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000717-149014) says that in the case of `NSMutableData`, the bytes are copied anyway.

Comment: he gets the raw bytes ... it doesnt magically realloc something in C .. anyway this is no answer

Comment: I think that this answer makes a good point. NSMutableData has a `appendData:` method. How should that work with a buffer given in the init call? - It works as expected with  NSData, but NSMutableData probably makes a mutable copy.

Comment: indeed the catch with `appendData:` makes sense.

Comment: What's the recommended approach to work with raw data (a uint8_t* allocated in C) then in Swift?