# NSData getting freed eventhough its used

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata, nsmutabledata

In below function I am trying to return `UIImage` pointer which is created from `NSData`

1. When I give option `freeWhenDone = YES` the `UIImage` displayed returned from here is white image.
2. When I give option `freeWhenDone = NO`

   - `UIImage` returned form here shows it as a black image.
   - When I pass `rgb_buffer` (char array) instead of `[rgbData bytes]` function1 and function2 work properly. Everything is fine.

Is it something to do with ARC?

```
Myfunction
{
    char *pu1_out_buffer = malloc(length);
    int width, height, stride;
    char *rgb_buffer = malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH);
pu1_out_buffer = datafromfile(FILE_PATH)  // initialized with some data , not important

/* rgb NSdata created from malloced rub buffer */
    NSMutableData *rgbData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:rgb_buffer
                                                     length:(u4_stride * u4_height * 3)
                                               freeWhenDone:YES];
[self function1:pu1_out_buffer
            rgb_buffer:(UWORD16 *)[rgbData bytes]
                        …]

    free(pu1_out_buffer); 
    UIImage *outUIImage  = [self function2:rgbData          
                                        width:u4_width
                                       height:u4_height
                                       stride:u4_stride];

    return outUIImage;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need to use dynamic memory allocation (malloc's)?

Comment: It is impossible to answer why your image is white or black without knowing `function1`, `function2`.

Comment: Unrelated but `pu1_out_buffer = datafromfile(FILE_PATH) ` = invalid syntax and a memory leak. `MyFunction {` is also invalid unless a macro, please post a real example.

Comment: Also why would you `malloc` the size of `BUFFER_LENGTH` but lie to `NSMutableData` and tell it `(u4_stride * u4_height * 3)`?

Comment: `rgb_buffer` is freed, which has been explained in your previous question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380363/problems-with-nsmutabledata-byteswithnocopy or its possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770265/nsmutabledata-datawithbytesnocopylengthfreewhendone-seems-to-make-a-copy-of-t. So it is unlikely that using `rgb_buffer` instead of `[rgbData bytes]` works "better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of issues with this code.

```
char *pu1_out_buffer = malloc(length);
pu1_out_buffer = datafromfile(FILE_PATH)  // initialized with some data , not important
```

That leaks the original `malloc`.

```
[self function1:pu1_out_buffer
        rgb_buffer:(UWORD16 *)[rgbData bytes]
                    …]
```

That method should be something like: `function1:rgbBuffer:`...

As for the crash, it is most likely for the reason Martin cites.   If you have ARC enabled, you are grabbing an *interior pointer* from the `NSMutableData` instance.  ARC can't associate the return value of `bytes` with the original data, assumes the data object is no longer being used, and releases it.

To fix, add:

`[rgbData bytes]` right before `return outUIImage;`.   That will let ARC know that the object is in use through the duration of the `function2:width:height:stride:` call.